# useradd with -d option do not create skeleton files

Tags: useradd, etc

When I create a user with `useradd` command in centos 5, the home directory is created and its /etc/skel files are copied to that directory but when i give `useradd` with `-d`option to some different path to home directory it does not create the skeloton files, like `.bachrc`, `.bash_history` etc.

If someone can give a hint so I can resolve this problem. Actually I need to execute some specific command .bashrc file but its not there. I created it manually but stil it does not executed that at time of user login.

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skeleton files are only copied when creating a home directory. Try adding the `-m` option.

Comment: Yes with `useradd  -md  /home/somedir/home1/ username` works!